# How do I show that non-extremal points are sum of two distinct points?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry

Let $a,b,c\in \mathbb{C}$.

Define $T=\{\lambda_1 a + \lambda_2 b + \lambda_3 c : 0\leq \lambda_i \leq 1, \lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3=1\}$. (This is a triangle with edges $a,b,c$)

Let $z\in T$ such that $z\neq a,b,c$.

In this case, how do I prove that there are two distinct points $x,y\in T$ such that $z=\frac{x+y}{2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $z \in T$ is not a vertex, at least two of the lambdas, say $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are strictly between $0$ and $1$.

So, assume that $z = \lambda_1 a + \lambda_2 b + \lambda_3 c$, and choose $\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}\eps> 0$ such that $\lambda_1 > \eps$ and $\lambda_2 < 1-\eps$. Put $x = (\lambda_1-\eps)a + (\lambda_2+\eps)b + \lambda_3 c$ and $y = (\lambda_1+\eps)a+(\lambda_2-\eps)b + \lambda_3c$.

It's probably helpful to draw a picture.